# ADODB.RecordSet Filter syntax

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

I am having an issue setting a filter on my `ADODB.RecordSet`

```
rs.Filter = "(password_date + " & password_valid & ") > Date()"
```

`password_date` is a date field, so I'm checking if the password has expired in this piece of logic (by later checking the record count)

But I get the following error, which I believe may be something to do with the syntax of the filter? I have tried a number of combinations of parentheses.

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'  Arguments are of the wrong type, are
>   out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Is it valid to do date arithmetic in a filter?

Comment: What's the value of password_valid

Comment: In this case it was 1

Comment: So the filter would be (password_date1)>Date()........

Comment: Errr no it would be `(password_date + 1) > Date()` as it says above. The + is part of the string

Comment: Does the code work without the filter ? Could it be because of some other part of your code?

Comment: Prior to the filter it worked fine. I.e. the main select query. I'm probably going to switch my logic to using DateDiff instead of ResultSet Filter

Comment: This seems to work: `" password_date  > #" & Date() - password_valid  & "#"` . `Filter` does not seem to like the other stuff. I can't explain why. It would be better if you can do the filtering in the query itself.